# Tile to CGPoint conversion with Retina display

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, tile

I have a project that uses a tilemap. I have a separate tilemap for low-res (29x29 Tilesize) and high-res (58x58). I have these methods to calculate tileCoord to position and back again.

```
    - (CGPoint)tileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    int x = position.x / _tileMap.tileSize.width;
    int y = ((_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - position.y) / _tileMap.tileSize.height;
    return ccp(x, y);
}

- (CGPoint)positionForTileCoord:(CGPoint)tileCoord {
    int x = (tileCoord.x * _tileMap.tileSize.width) + _tileMap.tileSize.width/2;
    int y = (_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - (tileCoord.y * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - _tileMap.tileSize.height/2;
    return ccp(x, y);
}
```

I got this from RayWenderLich and I do honeslty not understand how it works, and why it has to be so complicated. But this doesn't work when I use retina tilemaps, only on 480x320. Can someone clever come up with a way to make this work for HD? Does not have to work on low-res either, I do not plan on supporting sub-iOS 7.

I want the output to be in the low-res coordinate scale tho, as you might know, cocos2d does the resizing to HD for you. (By multiplying by two)

Comment: “Does not have to work on low-res either, I do not plan on supporting sub-iOS 7.”  If you want to support iPads natively, you need low-res, because the iPad mini is non-Retina regardless of iOS version.

Comment: @robmayoff I'll have another storyboard and code file for ipad, as im gonna do something special to utilise all that beautiful screen space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will work

```
- (CGPoint)tileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    int x = position.x/29;
    int y = ((11*29)-position.y) / 29;
    
    return ccp(x, y);
}

- (CGPoint)positionForTileCoord:(CGPoint)tileCoord {
    double x = tileCoord.x * 29 + 14.5;
    double y = (11*29) - (tileCoord.y * 29) - 14.5;

    return ccp(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you're trying to compute your map X coordinate:

```
int x = position.x / _tileMap.tileSize.width;
```

The problem here is that (as of [v0.99.5-rc0](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3ahow_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d), cocos2d generally uses **points** for positions, but `CCTMXTiledMap` always uses **pixels** for `tileSize`.  On a low-res device, 1 point = 1 pixel, but on a Retina device, 1 point = 2 pixels.  Thus on a Retina device, you need to multiply by 2.

You can use the `CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()` macro to fix this:

```
int x = CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() * position.x / _tileMap.tileSize.width;
```

Here you're trying to compute yoru map Y coordinate:

```
int y = ((_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - position.y) / _tileMap.tileSize.height;
```

The extra math here is trying to account for the difference between Cocos2D's normal coordinate system and your map's flipped coordinate system.  In standard Cartesian coordinates, the origin is at the lower left and Y coordinates increase as you move up.  In a flipped coordinate system, the origin is at the upper left and Y coordinates increase as you move down.  Thus you must subtract your position's Y coordinate from the height of the map (in scene units, which are points) to flip it to map coordinates.

The problem again is that `_tileMap.tileSize` is in pixels, not points.  You can again fix that by using `CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()`:

```
CGFloat tileHeight = _tileMap.tileSize.height / CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
int y = ((_tileMap.mapSize.height * tileHeight) - position.y) / tileHeight;
```

Comment: I dont have the balls to use capslock functions, i'll leave that to the big boys